# I have a red triangle appears at the top. why?

Tags: unity

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , I have a red triangle appears at the top. why?
I download updates when they arrive.
Here is the result of the command typed :

mahmoud@mahmoud-HP-620:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for mahmoud: 
Ign http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
Ign http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Get:1 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease
Get:2 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49,6 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release
Get:5 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49,6 kB]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [44,4 kB]
Get:7 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49,6 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [1 950 B] 
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [13,5 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [1 386 B]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [167 kB] 
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Get:12 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [168 kB]
Get:13 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [3 285 B]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [3 968 B]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [44,3 kB]
Get:16 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [52,6 kB] 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Get:17 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [4 241 B]
Get:18 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [392 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2 369 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-fr
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-fr 
Get:20 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [6 732 B]
Get:21 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [132 kB]
Get:22 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [9 673 B]
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Get:23 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources [2 422 B]
Get:24 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources [14 B]
Get:25 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources [14,5 kB]
Get:26 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources [2 669 B]
Get:27 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages [1 941 B]
Get:28 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:29 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages [12,9 kB]
Get:30 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [2 504 B]
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-fr
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-fr
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-fr
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-fr
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-fr
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-fr
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-fr
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-fr
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 1 233 kB in 2s (501 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/claudiocn/slm/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/claudiocn/slm/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
mahmoud@mahmoud-HP-620:~$

Comment: Did you try moving the mouse over it, and possibly left or right clicking to see if either says anything?

Comment: There is an update that needs to take place.  Where is the red triangle appearing?

Comment: If you haven't updated LTS since shortly after it came out, it will want to run the updates and upgrade the kernel to 3.2.0-30 and do several other security updates.  After updating the kernel it will then want to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had that triangle when I added the crebs ppa, which didn't exists anymore. Try `sudo apt-get update` and see if there is any errors.

Comment: I can't understand why someone would downwote this answer. He has a broken ppa as I've said.There are two 404 errors in your `sudo apt-get update` output, which causes errors in update, which is the reason of the red caoution triangle. remove `claudiocn` ppa. The problem will heal.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Some repositories change over time and ´apt-get update´ shows which one are not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Well there might be an error with one program that is running or it could be a background program running that messed up. The best way to find out what's wrong with it, would be to double click on it. Then it will get you the error and what's going on with this indicator.
It might be a good idea to check out the system, by running check disk, and go into terminal and type in, "sudo apt-get update".